# How to remove(or subtract)a "directory name" from a string?

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to create write something in **Java** that will take a file with a directory that has been saved as a string, such as: `C:\program\example.txt`, and remove everything up to the file so what is left is `example.txt`. The eventual desired behavior is that the code would subtract a user imputed main directory. The reason for doing this is because the way I want my program to store directory's is this
1. if the file is not contained in a sub directory(meaning, is contained in a main directory) store only the file name.
2. If the file is contained in a sub directory, at that before the file
So number 1 would look like 
"example.txt" and number 2 would look like "subdirectory\example.txt
That is why I though of deleting the main directory. That way the program would just somehow subtract the main directory from the directory of the file being opened and leave only the subfolders(if it is contained in any) in the file name.

I cannot figure out what kind of code would do this. The hard part is that when the file path is grabbed from the open file menu and added, it does add the double slashes. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: you can use split method. dont pls try something before asking

Comment: @raghavendra: Or you can do it properly.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i don't want to give total solution. he has try it out in different ways. it just a suggestion

Comment: @raghavendra: I meant "you can use split method, **or** you can do it properly." `split` is not the right way to do this.

Comment: may be it is why to use one more resource. without knowing things of his necessity we cannot estimate what he want.

Comment: ofcousr you can use file resource

Comment: I fail to understand what's wrong with this question. I think @Nicholas Hoffnagle did meet the "must include the desired behavior" rule. He made it perfectly clear what he needs.

Answer (score 6):

You can simply get the file name and assign to your variable, if you are looking to reuse your variable.

```
String sampleString = "C:\\program\\example.txt";
File file = new File(sampleString);
sample = file.getName();
```

Or you can simple substring by index of `"\"`

```
String sampleString = "C:\\program\\example.txt";
sampleString = sampleString.substring(sampleString.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
```

Comment: I believe the last snippet would get you "\example.txt" instead of "example.txt", if you don't add 1 to the argument of method substring.

Comment: Corrected now Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This has already been written for you, in the JDK's [`File` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html):

```
File file = new File("C:\\program\\example.txt");
System.out.println(file.getName());
```

`getName` will give you just the name of the file, without the path.

Comment: I apologize for incorrect English.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
Paths.get(path).getFileName();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use split() function in java and pass "/" as a seperator on "C:\program\example.txt" this string and then It will store "C:" on 0th location "program" on second location and "example.txt" on third location in an array.

Then if you access last location of array then you will get filename :)

Answer (score -1):

If it's for Windows, \ is the character that separates folders. You should identify the last \ and get the String that follows after that position.

To identify the last \ you can use

```
String s = "C:\\folder\\filename.txt" //every "\" in your path needs to be written as "\\" since you have to escape the character \
int indexOfLastBackslash = s.lastIndexOf("\\"); //the first \ is to escape the character \
```

Then you can get the file name with extension like this

```
String name = s.substring(indexOfLastBackslash + 1);
```

Please note that you should add 1 to the index of the last backslash, since in the method String.substring(int index) the argument is the index for the first character of the substring. If you don't add +1 you'll get "\filename.txt" instead of "filename.txt".

Comment: I updated the description to more accurately reflect the goal of my program. Thank you for all of your comments, they have all proven insightful.